# How can I insert a value into a string without concatenation?

Tags: php

My goal is to insert a variable's value directly into a string without concatenation using the `.` operator.

I tried like this:

```
$filename = 'some_file_name';
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename');
```

But this gives me `filename=$filename`, not `filename=some_file_name`.

How do I achieve this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$filename = "path/to/file.txt";
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
```

Comment: Don't you miss the concat operation? eg.`"".$x`

Comment: @tcurvelo no, the variable is inside the string

Comment: Oh nice, it really works with double quotes. Living and learning. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $document . '"');
```

Where $document is your variable. Added double quotes are here so you can have whitespaces in
your filenames.

Comment: There should not be double quotes

Comment: @zerkms Im not sure if it is the right way, but it was the only one for me to get spaces working correctly in Firefox. Can you provide me with alternitive?

Comment: that's interesting - I haven't used quotes there ever. Not sure about filenames with spaces. Probably I'm wrong, so, sorry about my comment then